# Mutate_ variable in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I'm trying to mutate 8 variables (Q31_1_ through Q31_8_) with a loop with the code below which gives me the following error message : *"unexpected '=' in :
"Ech_final_nom_BSA <- Ech_final_nom_BSA %>%
mutate_((as.name(paste("Q31_", i,"_", sep= ""))) ="*

What am I doing wrong?

```
for (i in 1:8) {

Ech_final_nom_BSA <- Ech_final_nom_BSA %>%
  mutate_(as.name(paste("Q31_", i,"_", sep= "")) = case_when(
                    as.name(paste("Q31_", i,"_", sep= "")) == 1 ~ 4,
                    as.name(paste("Q31_", i,"_", sep= "")) == 2 ~ 3,
                    as.name(paste("Q31_", i,"_", sep= "")) == 3 ~ 2,
                    as.name(paste("Q31_", i,"_", sep= "")) == 4 ~ 1,
                    T ~ as.numeric(as.character(as.name(paste("Q31_", i,"_", sep= ""))))
                    ))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a for loop. You can use `mutate` together with `across`:

```
Ech_final_nom_BSA %>%
  mutate(
    across(matches("^Q31_[1-8]_$"), ~case_when(
      .x %in% 1:4 ~ 4 - .x + 1,
      TRUE ~ .x
    )
    ) 
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Cettt! I ended up using a loop with base in the meantime but I'll keep your solution in mind.

Answer (score 1):

`mutate_` is discouraged from usage (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/se-deprecated.html). Instead, use e.g. `mutate_at` or `across` (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) and define a function similar to what you do in `case_when` -- except it could be more simple:

```
function(x) { ifelse(x %in% 1:4, 4:1[x], x) }
```

(or if you are certain `Q31_i` never lies outside of 1:4, it could be even more simple).